# Magento 2 Adding Customer Group to Invoice Header PDF

Tags: magento-2.1

Looking to add customer group to invoice and packing slips in magento 2. having a hard time figuring it out. please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to code this yourself rather than using an extension I suggest taking a look at

[Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php#L118)

Unfortunately the class has only a limited number of public and very long methods that we could use to hook into via a plugin. As you likely would want to add the new information in the middle of the getPdf() method a plugin would unfortunately not work here (as we wouldn't be able to call all the needed protected methods that would be needed).

This leaves the option to replace the whole class via a preference. To do so create a di.xml in your own extension with

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Fooman\Example\Model\OrderPdfInvoice" />
</config>
```

And then add your new implementation

```
class OrderPdfInvoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{
    public function getPdf()
    {
        //Copy complete method from parent class
        [...]
        //somewhere where you want to add the group
        $this->insertCustomerGroup($page, $order);
        [...]
    }

    public function insertCustomerGroup(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page, $order)
    {
        $groupId = $order->getCustomerGroupId();
        if ($groupId) {
            //TODO if you want the group name load it here 
            $page->drawText($groupId, 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $this->y -= 15;
        }
    }
}
```

Repeat for the same for the Shipment.